# Git (TortoiseGit) - How to revert a single file to a previous revision and then undo the revert?

Tags: windows, git, revision, tortoisegit

When using Git with TortoiseGit: Does somebody know how to revert a single file(or a complete repository) to a previous revision?

For example I have a repository containing multiple files. One file exists in three revisions (1 ; 2 ; 3). Now I want to change from revision 3 back to 2.

TortoiseGit offers a "Revert" function in the "Show log" dialog which allows to jump back to a specific revision, but this will revert your whole repository instead of a single file.

Also once I have reverted something, I don't have a clue how to undo the revert and jump back to the newest revision.

Answer (score 22):

From the command line: [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) is probably what you want.

The documentation shows an example of:

`$ git checkout master~2 Makefile`

to revert `Makefile` to two revisions back in the master branch

From within TortoiseGit (via Windows Explorer) it looks like you can do this with the following steps:

Navigate in Explorer to the folder where the file is.

Right-click on the file you want to revert, choose `Show log` from the TortoiseGit context menu

In the top section ("graph") select the revision that has the version of the file you want to revert to

In the third section (file list) right-click the file and choose `Revert to this revision`

You should get a message like `1 files revert to e19a77`

Comment: Yes you are right, this works perfect with git command line tools, but i am searching for the corresponding functionality in TortoiseGit which also uses git command line tools in the background.

Comment: Seems to be not possible with the current version of TortoiseGit.

Comment: I think I figured this out with TortoiseGit, see edited answer.

Answer (score 22):

It is also possible to get a specific file:

- Right-click on the file
- Choose the menu item: Git Show Log

TortoiseGit show a dialog with a list of all revisions

- Click on the prior revision (2)

In a list in the bottom of the dialog it shows all the files associated with the commit

- Find the file you are looking to view
- Right-click on that file and Save Revision To
- This will save that previous revision of the file with the commit number concatenated on the file

For example:
 - original file is file.txt
 - revision 2 will save as file-67b51a8.txt

I'm using TortoiseGit v2.2.0.0

Comment: This is the best answer! the other answers are probably for previous versions of TortoiseGit before they added this functionality.

Comment: You can also directly click __Revert to this revision__ to reset _only that file_ to what it looked like in that commit. This doesn't mess with the branch you're checked out on.

Comment: This is really painful if that revision is a rename, you simply get an error saying no such path exists.

Answer (score 17):

In TortoiseGit the answer is to right-click the project folder and click Show Log, then right-click the change you want to roll back to and click Switch/Checkout to this... . It will let you then proceed from that weird place in the commit stack, or branch in case you plan to commit and want things to stay sane.

Comment: I think it will change all project

Comment: The question asks for either: "revert a single file(or a complete repository) to a previous revision"

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047540/) shows how to revert only __1 file__ to a previous commit

Answer (score 8):

Updated my answer, based on these comments:

- [by Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669917/git-tortoisegit-how-to-change-the-head-to-a-previous-revision#comment1549967_1670035).
- [by mlibby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669917/git-tortoisegit-how-to-change-the-head-to-a-previous-revision#comment1550721_1670035)
- [by Chris Moschini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669917/git-tortoisegit-how-to-change-the-head-to-a-previous-revision#comment56980131_33750731)

---

Suppose the working tree is clean and you want:

1. Checkout some file(s) of its previous revision
2. Testing
3. Revert to current revision

---

1. Checkout some file(s) of its previous revision

   (a) Right click the file you want to revert and Show Log for that file

   [image]

   (b) Right click the file in file list and perform **Revert to parent revision**

   [image]

   [image]

   (c) repeat (a), (b) until you get all files you want.

   [image]
2. Testing
3. Revert to current revision

   (a) perform *Revert...* in context menu of explorer

   This way, you can choose the file(s) you want to revert.

   (b) or this quick way: perform **Reset Hard** in Log dialog

   This way, all changed files revert. (=> Lost all working dir changes)

   [image]

   [image]

(Tested on TortoiseGit 1.8.16.1, GfW 2.6.4.windows.1, Win 10 64bit)

Comment: This is incorrect. What version of TortoiseGit is this? I don't think "Revert to parent revision" is even present anymore. Revert is for destroying local workspace changes. The question here is asking to roll back to an older version and return to the current version later, not destroy the current version.

Comment: The Revert feature is still doing something different from what the asker was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For Tortoise Version 2.3.0:

You can do it in several ways, but fastest i think is that:

1. Right click on the file
2. Click the menu option "Diff with previous version"
3. Right click on the left (previous) version of file
4. Click the menu option "Use this whole file"
5. Save the changes (ctrl+s)

Comment: Yap! Fast way. :)