# TortoiseGit: How to revert/undo 'git checkout <SPECIFIC BRANCH>

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I know how to checkout a specific branch from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669917/git-tortoisegit-how-to-change-the-head-to-a-previous-revision), but after having done so (checkout on same branch), I wish to now 'git checkout head' to get back to the latest revision.

One way is to git pull from remote and merge that way, but is there a way I can do this without depending on remote?

Please tell me how to do this on TortoiseGit, not command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. TortoiseGit -> Show Log
2. Right click branch name hyperlink on top left corner
3. You have a short history of branches, select master
4. Right click the first commit in log list, switch / checkout to master

Comment: As an added point if right click doesn't show it up you can left-click on the hyperlink of branch name and manually select master, should work too! Thanks @linquize!