# What is the difference between Revert To This Revision and ... To Parent

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33750731/4906), someone mentions Reverting to Parent version. What is the difference between that and This Version?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- If you select "Revert to this revision" the file "src/Git/Git.cpp" in your working tree is replaced with the version of the selected commit (i.e., `617257855` in your case).
- If you select "Revert to parent revision" the file "src/Git/Git.cpp" in your working tree is replaced with the version prior to the selected commit (i.e., excluding the changes by the selected commit - this is a shortcut, that you don't need to select the commit in which the file was changed before in order to restore it to that state, i.e., `617257855~1` in your case).